# need help in making key value pair in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have this code:

```
   while i<len(line):
        if re.findall(pattern, line[i]):
            k,v = line[i].split('=')
            print k
            token = dict(k=v)
            print token
            break
```

and the result I'm getting is :

```
ptk
{'k': 'ptk_first'}
```

how to make this few lines of code nicer and dictionary that will look like this:

```
{'ptk': 'ptk_first'}
```

Comment: Why are you using a ``while`` loop here? You are not even advancing ``i``. Please give a complete example we can run to see the output.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's only part of the code, you can assume that i=0

Comment: You still haven't given us ``pattern``. In future questions, give a [short, complete, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/). My main point about the loop is that ``i`` shouldn't exist - why use a ``while`` loop to loop over a sequence instead of a ``for`` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [112]: line="ptk=ptk_first" 

In [113]: dict([line.split("=")])
Out[113]: {'ptk': 'ptk_first'}
```

for your code:

```
for line in lines:
    if re.findall(pattern, line):
        token = dict([line.split("=")])
        print token
```

Comment: @wim actually they're necessary, or else I've to use a tuple `dict((line.split("="),))`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: off-topic question: what are you copy/pasting code from? How do I enable the `In [lineno]` feature on my terminal(?)

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in lines:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        k,v = line.split('=')
        token = {k:v}
        print token
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
lines="""\
key1=data on the rest of line 1
key2=data on the rest of line 2
key3=data on line 3"""

d={}
for line in lines.splitlines():
    k,v=line.split('=')
    d[k]=v

print d
```

Answer (score 1):

with regex you can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> lines="""
... ptk=ptk_first
... ptk1=ptk_second
... """
>>> dict(re.findall('(\w+)=(\w+)',lines,re.M))
{'ptk1': 'ptk_second', 'ptk': 'ptk_first'}
```